# How to change the date format in order-detail?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to change the date format of order-detail. Right now it is coming in "8 06Europe/Amsterdam18 2014" and I want this in 26-06-2014 like: [here is link](http://indepieremegoggel.nl/?page_id=1896&bestelling-ontvangen=3574&key=wc_order_53ac47d5921b5).
Any help would be appreciated.

Note: this site is now in Dutch . Only date format needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_date = "2014-06-26";// may be in date format or in date time format as like "2014-06-26 00:00:00"
$date=date_create($your_date,timezone_open("Europe/Amsterdam"));
echo date_format($date,"d-m-Y");//gives output->   26-06-2014
```